# Is it Possible to use one site collection content type in another site collection

Tags: content-type, site-collection

I have two Site Collections

- Site Collection A
- Site Collection B

I have **Custom Content type** in **Site Collection A**.

I have to use same content type in **Site Collection B**.

So is it Possible to use one site collection content type in another site collection.
If yes then how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the Content type hub feature to share content type across site collections.

how to do it:

1) Create a source site collection

2) Activate Content type hub site collection feature on it.

3) Create a content type and the site columns inside this site collection

4) After that run the below powershell script

```
$mms = Get-SPServiceApplication -Name "Managed Metadata Service"

Set-SPMetadataServiceApplication -Identity $mms -HubUri "https://servername/sites/ContentTypeHubSite/"

Write-Host "Set content type hub uri"

$mmsp = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | ? {$_.DisplayName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"} 

Set-SPMetadataServiceApplicationProxy -Identity $mmsp -ContentTypeSyndicationEnabled -ContentTypePushdownEnabled -Confirm:$false

Write-Host "Content type syndication enabled "
```

If you dont want to run powershell, you can go to central admin > manage service application > managed metadata service application.  Configure it as below:

[image]

After that click on the proxy:

[image]

And configure it as below:

[image]

5) After that, publish your content type from "Manage Publishing For this Content Type" by going to your content type in source site collection.

6) Now , go to the destination site collection to which content type is required.

7) here, go to Site Settings and Select the "Content Type Publishing".

8) Your content type would be visible now. If its not visible immediately, you need to run the `Content type subscriber` timer job. It runs on hourly basis.

Reference - [Create Content Type Hub in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/create-content-type-hub-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[Using content type hub in SP 2013](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Use-Content-Type-Hub-in-SharePoint-2013)

My 2 Rupees on this , instead of doing all this, just create a visual studio project solution and create the content type and site columns inside it. After that, deploy the the solution and activate the feature on the site collections that require the content types. Personally, I am not a big fan of this feature, I use in SP online because I cant do wsp deployment there and there is no other option. But if its On Premise environment, I would go with the wsp approach. The hub approach is slow and in case there is some issue its a bit difficult to debug and has more headaches compared to wsp. But this is strictly my opinion, your experience could be different :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes , this can be done by the implementation of **Content Type Hub**

here we need to create all these content types in a site collection from where we can publish these content types and can use those published Content Type in other site collections.

The site Collection need to configured as a Content Type Hub by Activating the feature **Content Type Syndication Hub**

Metadata Service need to be configured to support this .

refer this http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-to-Use-Content-Type-Hub-in-SharePoint-2013 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to push content types to multiple site collections using a **Content Type Hub**.

Basic Overview of **Content Type Syndication**:

1. Create a **Content Type Hub** Site Collection
2. Configure **Content Type Hub** URL in the Manged Metadata Service Application
3. Create Content Types in the Content Type Hub Site Collection
4. Publish those Content Types to other Site Collections.

More Information: https://collab365.community/understanding-content-type-hub-cth-in-sharepoint-2013/